# Rect drawn with graphics appear below background of BorderContainer

Tags: apache-flex, drawing

In a Flex component that inherits from BorderContainer I'm overriding the updateDisplayList function to draw a rect:

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth : Number, unscaledHeight : Number) : void
{
    this.graphics.clear();
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight); // If ommited the rect is shown properly
    drawRects(); // Just calls graphics.drawRoundedRect
}
```

The problem is the rectangles I draw appear below the container's white background, instead of being drawn on top of it. If I remove the call to super.updateDisplayList I see the rect drawn correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, using the graphics API will always draw to the actual sprite, below everything. Instead of using graphics, use Spark primitives such as Rect.

AS3:

```
var rect:Rect = new Rect();
rect.id = "backgroundRect";
rect.fill = new SolidColor();
rect.fill.color = 0xFFFFFF;
addElement(rect);
```

MXML:

```
<s:Rect id="backgroundRect" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"  >
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="#FFFFFF"/>
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```

EDIT : If you're not using Spark, then I guess a solution would be using a lightweight graphic component (sorry for being vague, my knowledge of MX is really limited) and use the graphics API on that component instead. That way diplay order should work.

Comment: I'm afraid Spark is not an option. I need to draw thousands of rects really fast. What kind of lightweight component did you have in mind?

Comment: As I said, I'm not familiar with MX components, but the most basic of display objects that implements IVisualElement would do just fine. Maybe mx:Container or mx:UIComponent ?

Comment: UIComponent is the lightweightest component. Next you'll have to deal with Sprite which is poorly handled by Flex.

Answer (score 0):

OP here. It seems that by moving the drawing code to the skin of my component everything works as expected.